# Keras installed but not importing (rpi)

Tags: python, keras, raspberry-pi

I successfully installed Keras on my Raspberry Pi using the instructions here:
https://medium.com/@abhizcc/installing-latest-tensor-flow-and-keras-on-raspberry-pi-aac7dbf95f2

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install gfortran
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py
sudo pip3 install keras
```

But when I try to import keras into a jupyter notebook (Python 3) or to a python shell, it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what interpreter you are using with:
`which python` and check where keras is installed with `pip show keras`.

The problem is that the python you are using in jupyter and the shell is not the one for which you installed keras.